# ng-pattern not working in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have a regex pattern as `(http(s)?://)?([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ;,./?%&=]*)?` which is working fine if I use some online tool to check it but when i use it in ng-pattern as `ng-pattern="(http(s)?://)?([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ;,./?%&=]*)?"` it is throwing error?

```
Invalid regular expression: /^(http(s)?://)?([w-]+.)+[w-]+(/[w- ;,./?%&=]*)?$/: Range out of order in character class
```

I have searched many questions over this issue but none seems to be working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change it to

```
(http(s)?:\/\/)?([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(\/[\w- ;,.\/?%&=]*)?
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign:

```
$scope.regex = "(http(s)?://)?([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ;,./?%&=]*)?";
```

And then write:

```
ng-pattern="{{regex}}"
```